# wrap jquery ui datepicker widgets with link to individual month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been using the jquery ui datepicker http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and have run into a problem that I hope you could help with. At the moment I have created a multi month grid of datepickers showing every month of the year. What I want to do is alter the header of each datepicker so the month name has a link attached.

The idea being that clicking on the month name will take the user to another page where a larger version of that month is shown. My question is how can i wrap the header of each datepicker with a link?

```
$( '#calendargrid' ).datepicker( { 
     dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'], numberOfMonths: [3,4]
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin doesn't support what you want, but you can do some tricky code to allow your desire behaviour.

Maybe adding some classes and elements after the plugin set up your datepicker will work. Or you can use `month` array. I did some test and this array support HTML code:

```
$("#calendargrid").datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    numberOfMonths: [3,4]
    monthNames: [
        '<a id="jan" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">January</a>',
        '<a id="feb" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">February</a>',
        '<a id="mar" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">March</a>',
        '<a id="april" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">April</a>',
        '<a id="may" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">May</a>',
        '<a id="june" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">June</a>',
        '<a id="july" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">July</a>',
        '<a id="aug" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">August</a>',
        '<a id="sep" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">September</a>',
        '<a id="oct" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">October</a>',
        '<a id="nov" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">November</a>',
        '<a id="dic" onclick="seeMonth(this.id)">December</a>']
});

function seeMonth(monthName) {
    // Redirect the user to the other page
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise you could just alter the headings like that.

Comment: I tried a difficult way adding some styles and DOM after the plugin setup, but this way is easier as hell! :D